# How to show animation(like logo of application) while executing doInBackground() in android

Tags: android, android-asynctask, jquery-animate

I want to show animated app logo instead of progress dialog or progress bar when ever doInBackground() method of Async Task is executed.

Please see the reference of Expedia Android App..

Please help me. Thanks in advance...

Comment: Do you have `.gif` for animation ?

Comment: I don't have any idea please suggest me the step.

Comment: Hi @sambal 
In onPreExecute()  method  we can call custom dialog progress bar as you can see my post

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16607676/cancel-or-dismiss-android-alert-dialogue/16608808#16608808

Answer (score 1):

```
You should use custom dialog in  onPreExecute()



Dialog mDialog = new Dialog(mContext,
                android.R.style.Theme_Translucent_NoTitleBar);
        mDialog.setContentView(R.layout.progressbar);
        mDialog.setCancelable(false);
        mDialog.show();`enter code here`


<>>>....This is layout of you custom dialogbar........<<<<<<<<<<<

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="150dip"
    android:layout_height="150dip"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:background="@drawable/progressbar_shap"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textview"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:text="Please Wait..."
         android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <ProgressBar
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:indeterminateDrawable="@drawable/my_progress_indetermine" >
    </ProgressBar>

</RelativeLayout>


<...................Giving shape to dialog  progressbar_shap................>

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/shape_my" >

    <stroke
        android:width="2dp"
        android:color="#636161" />

    <padding
        android:bottom="20dp"
        android:left="20dp"
        android:right="20dp"
        android:top="20dp" />

    <corners android:radius="24dp" />

    <solid android:color="#88000000" />

</shape>

<.................. my_progress_indetermine .................>

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<animated-rotate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:drawable="@drawable/please_wait"
        android:pivotX="50%"
        android:pivotY="50%" />
```

Answer (score 0):

as Rank pointed out

```
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            //do animation stuff here
            super.onPreExecute();
        }
```

then on

```
protected void onPostExecute(Object result) {
        //end animation here
        super.onPostExecute();  
        }
```